# Android: trying to start BluetoothSettings activity Force Closes with NullPointerException

Tags: android, bluetooth, settings

I'm trying to bring up the standard window for Bluetooth Settings (with Device name, Discoverability etc).

However, general approach with `startActivity(intent)` ends with `NullPointerException` pointing to `BluetoothSettings.java onCreate:135`.

Checking with the Android code, I've found that at `line 135` they get some extras from the intent. So, I prepare the same extras (names I've found in android core `BluetoothDevicePicker` interface) and issue it -- the same effect with `NullPointerException`.

Might be the wrongs names of the extras I prepare?

So is there a way I can see those extras (with names especially) from the intent the system itself submits when I open Bluetooth Settings manually acting like a user?

Many thanks.

My code is:

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent();
settingsIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings");
settingsIntent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.LAUNCH_PACKAGE", "mypackage.bttoggle");
settingsIntent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.DEVICE_PICKER_LAUNCH_CLASS", "mypackage.bttoggle.BluetoothWidget");
PendingIntent settingsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, settingsIntent, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnSettings, settingsPendingIntent);
```

It's a widget so I need to use `PendingIntent`.

This code get the following Exception at runtime:

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due
>   to uncaught exception ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2621)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:126)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1932)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings.onCreate(BluetoothSettings.java:135)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4905):     ... 11 more

After investigating, I found that at `line 135` in `BluetoothSettings.java` there is:

```java
public class BluetoothSettings extends PreferenceActivity {

...
 132             mNeedAuth = intent.getBooleanExtra(BluetoothDevicePicker.EXTRA_NEED_AUTH, false);
 133             mFilterType = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevicePicker.EXTRA_FILTER_TYPE,
 134                     BluetoothDevicePicker.FILTER_TYPE_ALL);
 135             mLaunchPackage = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevicePicker.EXTRA_LAUNCH_PACKAGE);
 136             mLaunchClass = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothDevicePicker.EXTRA_LAUNCH_CLASS);
...
```

I looked into `BluetoothDevicePicker` to find the names of the extras:

```
public interface BluetoothDevicePicker {
    public static final String EXTRA_NEED_AUTH =
            "android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.NEED_AUTH";
    public static final String EXTRA_FILTER_TYPE =
            "android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.FILTER_TYPE";
    public static final String EXTRA_LAUNCH_PACKAGE =
            "android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.LAUNCH_PACKAGE";
    public static final String EXTRA_LAUNCH_CLASS =
            "android.bluetooth.devicepicker.extra.DEVICE_PICKER_LAUNCH_CLASS";
```

so I use them in my code to prepare those particular extras.

Comment: Please show a code snippet of the intent you are creating, and the full stacktrace of the null pointer.